# undocumented ai_flags value (0x80000000) in structure addrinfoex on Win 8?

Tags: c, dns, windows-8, winsock2

Does anybody knows this about the ai_flags value in the structure addrinfoex? The value 0x80000000 is not documented for ai_flags in MSDN. I got this on Windows 8. 
I have following code:

==================================

```
ADDRINFOEX  hints; 
ADDRINFOEX  *result = NULL; 
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints)); 
hints.ai_flags = AI_FQDN | AI_CANONNAME; 
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; 
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; 
GetAddrInfoExW(L"www.google.com", 
                        0, 
                        NS_DNS, 
                        0, 
                        &hints, 
                        &pResult, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0);
```

==================================

the GetAddrInfoExW() succeeds but in the returned pResult data structure, ai_flags equals to 0x80000000. 
Does anyone know the meaning of 0x80000000? Why it returns 0x80000000?

Thanks a lot.